# What sort of clustering/optimization problem is this and is there a specific algorithm/method to solve it?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, clustering

I have a population which consist of *n* customers, each of them has an associated rate *r* and an annual purchase volume *apv*. Rate and volume are negative correlated to some extent:

[image]

The average weighted rate of the population is P. I want to define 5 volume buckets (defined by boundaries *APV1, APV2, APV3, APV4*) and apply a different rate (*R1*, ..., *R5*) to each volume bucket (but the same to all customers within the same bucket as opposed to today where it is different for each individual) with the condition that 1) the average weighted rate of the population is still P and that 2) it is optimized so the sum of the absolute rate variation of each customer is minimal

In other words, I want to find the constants for the function:
[image]

Such that:

[image]

and

[image]

is as small as possible.

I thought about using some basic ML clustering algorithms which I am familiar with such as KMeans but I think that would not work here. Any help is highly appreciated.**strong text**

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use dynamic programming.  See the "Segmented Least Squares" problem in Kleinberg and Tardos' book for a starting point.  Slides are here (see Section 6.3): https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pearson/06DynamicProgramming.pdf